# String is null after reading it from header

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've got a .htaccess file, which has some redirections:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^termekek/kategoriak/?$    kategoriak.php    [NC,L]    # Kategóriák rd
RewriteRule    ^termekek/?$    kategoriak.php    [NC,L]    # Kategóriák rd
RewriteRule    ^termekek/kategoriak/([A-Za-z]+)/([0-9-])/?$    kategoria.php?category_name=$1&page_number=$2    [QSA,NC,L]    # Kategória rd
RewriteRule    ^termekek/kategoriak/([A-Za-z]+)/?$    kategoria.php?category_name=$1&page_number=1    [QSA,NC,L]    # Kategória rd
RewriteRule    ^termekek/kategoriak/([A-Za-z]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    termek.php?category_name=$1&product_name=$2    [QSA,NC,L]    # Termék rd

RewriteRule    ^hir/([A-Za-z-0-9-]+)/?$    hir.php?seo_link=$1   [QSA,L]    # Hírek rd

RewriteRule    ^rolunk/?$    rolunk.php    [NC,L]    # Márka rd
RewriteRule    ^markaboltok/?$    markaboltok.php    [NC,L]    # Márkaboltok rd
RewriteRule    ^kapcsolat/?$    kapcsolat.php    [NC,L]    # Kapcsolat rd
RewriteRule    ^hirek/?$    hirek.php    [NC,L]    # Hírek rd

RewriteRule    ^404/?$    404.php    [NC,L]   # 404 error rd

ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/404/
```

and I have one single page which doesn't want to behave as I'd like to.

```
<?php
include 'functions.php';
include 'config/connection.php';

$seo_link = $_GET['seo_link'];
…
```

$seo_link is null, but other websites are working as intended even with the redirections. Is there any problem with my redirection or what ?
The pattern what I'd like to read is: http://www.example.com/hir.php?seo_link=something-from-the-database

which would be translated to: http://www.example.com/hir/something-from-the-database/

Thanks in advance !

Comment: If you use `RewriteRule    ^RewriteRule    ^hir/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/$    hir.php?seo_link=$1` what's the result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the 'hir' part of the rewrite rule is colliding with the filename 'hir.php'.

Try adjusting it so that the first part of the rewrite rule is different from the filename:

```
RewriteRule    ^hir2/([A-Za-z-0-9-]+)/?$    hir.php?seo_link=$1   [QSA,L]    # Hírek rd
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thank you for your help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You've an extra `-` on your regex (`z-0`), try using:

```
RewriteRule    ^hir/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/$    hir.php?seo_link=$1   [QSA,L]    # Hírek rd
```